# Using web3, how can you get the tx cost and data/payload for a given transaction?

Tags: transactions, web3js, fees, calldata

Using web3, how can you get the `Tx cost` and `data/payload` for a given transaction?

`getTransaction(tx#)` returns everything but those 2 values. This information seems to be available via blockchain explorers such as etherchain.org

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`web3.eth.getTransaction` has an `input` property, which is the /payload for a given transaction.

The cost of a transaction is `gasUsed` multiplied by `gasPrice`.
[`web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgettransactionreceipt) has the `gasUsed` property.  `web3.eth.getTransaction` has `gasPrice`.  Since the unit for `gasPrice` is wei, divide by 1e18 to get the Ether cost of a transaction.